# "Call target does not contain any signature" for call to super() without typings file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make Polymer 2.0 work with Typescript and am running into issues when making a constructor where libraries - including Polymer 2 - do not expose a proper typings file. In the simplest case:

```
class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
    public static is = 'my-view1';

    constructor() {
        super(); // [ts] Call target does not contain any signature
    }
}
```

To make it compile at all without the constructor, I've done a `declare var Polymer: any;` in a main `.d.ts` file.

Now, I have two questions:

1. How (if at all) can I make typescript ignore this and just assume there's a super constructor it can call?
2. How (if at all) do I declare a typings file that contains a signature for the super class? I haven't been able to find the right documentation for this (and the various use cases I've run into so far) yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can just expand your declaration to include a constructor in the `Element` property:

```
declare var Polymer: {
    Element: {
        new ();
    }
};
```

For your second question, you can just move this to a `*.d.ts` file. See the [documentation on creating declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

### Why

Usually, this is because you there is conditional logic which alters what the superclass can be. For instance --

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        super(/* anything */);
    }
}
class B {
    constructor() {
        super(/* anything */);
    }
}

var X = { prod: A, qa: A, dev: B, mock: B }[ environment.type ];  // inline map

class C extends X {
    constructor() {
        super(/* anything */);
    }
}
```

-- can yield this behavior if `type` is not even declared on `environment`, or [potentially] if TypeScript especially thinks that `X` could be something other that a class which takes the arguments being provided by the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
class MyView1 extends (Polymer.Element as {new(): any}) {
    ...
}
```